# Вывести в label значение, соответствующее выбранной строке listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

Что передавать в `label.config(text=)`, чтобы при нажатии на `listbox1` в `label` выводилось значение `111`; при нажатии `listbox2` выводилось значение `222` и тд...

```
from tkinter import *

topics = [('1', '111'),
          ('2', '222'),
          ('3', '333')]


def click_listbox(event):
    label.config(text=?)



root = Tk()
root.title("Some Label")
root.geometry("800x600")

topics_listbox = Listbox()
for topic in topics:
    topics_listbox.insert(END, topic[0])


label = Label()

message_entry = Entry(width=70)

message_button = Button(text="Отправить")

topics_listbox.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.01, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.98)
topics_listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", click_listbox)
label.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.01)
message_entry.place(x=260, y=550)
message_button.place(x=700, y=550)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. у вас `topics` список, то нужно получить индекс выбранной строки, потом значение из списка по этому индексу:

```
def click_listbox(event):
    # event.widget - виджет, который вызвал событие, в данном случае listbox
    # event.widget.curselection()[0] - индекс выбранной строки
    # topics_listbox.curselection()[0] - то же самое (в данном случае event.widget is topics_listbox)
    index = event.widget.curselection()[0]
    label.config(text=topics[index][1])
```

Если нужно именно из `dict`, то:

```
topics_dict = dict(topics)

def click_listbox(event):
    # Получаем текст выбранной строки, используем его как ключ в словаре:
    key = topics_listbox.get(topics_listbox.curselection()[0])
    label.config(text=topics_dict[key])
```

Пользовался информацией отсюда: [The Tkinter Listbox Widget](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm)